# AJAX/jQuery form submission difficulties

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have managed to get the following code to work to submit a form using AJAX and update the results div of my website, it works fine...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){    
     $("#myform").validate({         
     debug: false,    
     rules: {           
      guess: {              
             min: 0,                
             number: true            
             }       
            },       
     messages: {           
        guess: "Please enter a valid guess.",     
      },       
    submitHandler: function(form) {             // do other stuff for a valid form             
    $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
              $('#results').html(data);         
     });        
   }   
  }); 
});
</script>
```

Am I right in thinking that if I have another form that I want to send to "process2.php" that updates a different part of the webpage I need to have another copy of the same script, but effectively call my second form "form2"  and chage the #myform --> #myform2  and the #results --> #new_div ??

I have tried getting it to work on a complete new page, and it works OK when I ask it to print something from process2.php to the screen, but when I try and get it to do something with the passed variables (in this case name and email) it doesn't even print the results of the php anymore.

my process.php  INSERTS the guess (a number) into a database of guesses..  along with the member_id (also a number)..

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. It seems to be when I include the wp_blog_header.php on my process2.php (however that header is in process.php WHICH WORKS FINE).. if I do not include that line, my connection to the database fails and I cannot INSERT into tables...

I have no idea what else I can do or what additional info I need?

my new form is

Name 
Email

and my new javafunction becomes

```
script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform2").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process2.php', $("#myform2").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Is this a problem with my coding, or is it something to do with my process2.php (which is almost EXACTLY the same as my process.php) apart from I am INSERTING into a different database table, a name and an email... yet it doesn't seem to work...

so the code in the PHP is like
    "INSERT into 'new_table' ('name', 'email') VALUES (" . $_POST['name'] "," $_POST['email'] . ")";

but as soon as I have the line

include(wp-blog-header.php)   it seems to fall over...   hmmmmmm - I'm SO lost :(

Comment: It may be worth installing something like [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) so that you can see the AJAX calls being submitted, as well as the responses received. This will give you an indication of whether it's a problem with your Javascript or the server-side code.

Comment: I'll give that a go, the AJAX seems to work because it prints out a test (i.e. I made process2.php blank with just print "TESTING")... so the form invoked process2.php and it completed, so to me it looks to be something inside the include I use to get use of the wordpress functions.

Answer (score 0):

If it works without AJAX, this plugin makes it really easy to convert a plain form into using AJAX: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/